# Xamarin Forms ImageRenderer Inaccessible

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've attempt to install GlideX to a production Xamarin forms app on 3.6.0
(Can't update to 4+ currently).

In

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

I have

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental"); 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle); 
Android.Glide.Forms.Init(this);
```

However as soon as the first Xamarin forms page is due to render (I has zero custom controls, it is just some images and a button) I get.

Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.ImageRenderer..ctor(Android.Content.Context)' is inaccessible from method `Android.Glide.ImageRenderer..ctor(Android.Content.Context)

Can't for the life of me see what I am missing

Comment: Full stack https://pastebin.com/f4QGG5bH

Comment: Where you have this issue, so can you post some code here? About using GlideX.Forms, I follow this article and have no issue:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/glidex-fast-images-android/

Comment: I tried the sample and have the same issue. Maybe I need to update the Xamarin.Android build also ?

Comment: because it is not the correct answer. you just restated what the crash says, not why the two are incompatible in this instance. A correct answer actually has an answer.

Comment: ,My xamarin.forms version is 4.3.0.778476-pre1, and I have no issue, so please try to update Xamarin.Forms and try again. If you still have the same issue, please provide simple sample that can reproduce this issue on github.

Comment: As explained project can't be updated , to.risky at this stage. Answer below

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dependency for the nuget was incorrect and requires a minimum of forms 4.0, rather than the 3.5 as listed.
Solution is either newer version of forms, or older version of nuget.

https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex/issues/54